# Shell script self-destruct and/or replace

Tags: shell

I have read that you can self destruct a script safely by adding `rm script.sh` anywhere in the script and the system will safely queue the file deletion until after the script is done running, but I have also read that it is *not* safe to modify a script within itself via `cp newscript.sh script.sh` because the buffer may start reading in `newscript.sh` before `script.sh` is done running.  However, is the following safe?

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
*some commands*
replace.sh &
exit 0
```

**replace.sh** (waits until `script.sh` finishes to do replacment)

```
#!/bin/sh
while pidof -x script.sh
do
    sleep 1
done
cp newscript.sh script.sh
rm newscript.sh replace.sh
exit 0
```

**Context**

I'm using `rc.local` to run a one-time script at boot, but since it's only once, I want to restore `rc.local` with a backup I took.  I'm trying to avoid messing with `init.d` and `systemd`, etc.  I have tested whether I can successfully use a backgrounded process invoked by `rc.local` to test whether `rc.local` is still running and I can.

Comment: At least you have a race condition here: If script.sh is restarted again, after the loop has finished, but before cp can do its work, you are out of luck. The time window for this is small, but it is still a possibility.

Comment: Can you lock a script to prevent that?

Comment: Actually, never mind.  rc.local only runs once, and I don't think I would ever try this in any other context.